# Editing XML file but not able to pinpoint the node

Tags: xml, powershell

I have to edit an XML with PowerShell.

I need replacing:

```
<hash n="DBConfig">
      <hash n="EXTENSION"/>

      <hash n="URLFileChooserPaths">
         <list n="CARTDIR">
            <url path="../../../../../"/>
         </list>
         <list n="CARTSCRIPTDIR">
            <url path="../../../../../"/>
         </list>
         <list n="DEFAULT_CONTEXT">
            <url path="../../../../../"/>
         </list>
         <list n="DIFFDIR">
            <url path="../../../../../"/>

         </list>
      </hash>
```

With:

```
<hash n="DBConfig">
      <hash n="EXTENSION"/>
      <value n="TNS_NAMES_DIR" v="O:\Dev6i\Sqlnet"/>
      <hash n="URLFileChooserPaths">
         <list n="ConfigClientPanel.Dialog.Home">
            <url path="../../../../../../../Oracl11GR2_64/product/11.2.0/client_1/"/>
         </list>
         <list n="TNS_NAMES_DIR">
            <url protocol="file" path="/x:/Dev6i/Sqlnet"/>
            <url protocol="file" path="/x:/Dev6i/Sqlnet/"/>
         </list>
      </hash>
      <value n="URLFileChooserPaths.persisted" v="true"/>
      <value n="USE_THICK_DRIVER" v="true"/>
   </hash>
```

But:

```
$x="C:\Sovgarde\product-preferences.xml"
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $x
```

`$xml.preferences.hash.n.DBConfig` is returning nothing.
The best would be to replace the whole section but I don't know how.

```
$xml.preferences.hash.n="DBCONFIG"
La propriété « n » est introuvable dans cet objet. Vérifiez qu’elle existe et qu’elle peut être définie.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ $xml.preferences.hash.n="DBCONFIG"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

How may I handle that task?

The whole XML.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ide:preferences xmlns:ide="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ide/hash">
   <hash n="CodeEditorBookmarkOptions">
      <list n="persistedBookmarks"/>
   </hash>
   <hash n="CodingStyleProfiles">
      <hash n="Java Code Conventions">
         <value n="blanklines.after_last_member" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.before_field" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.before_first_class" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.before_first_member" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.before_member_class" v="1"/>
         <value n="blanklines.before_method" v="1"/>
         <value n="blanklines.empty_anonymous" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.empty_block" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.empty_class" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.empty_method" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.imports_after" v="1"/>
         <value n="blanklines.package_after" v="1"/>
         <value n="blanklines.preserve_count" v="2"/>
         <value n="field.prefix"/>
         <value n="field.suffix"/>
         <value n="import.group_imports" v="true"/>
         <value n="import.group_package_depth" v="2"/>
         <value n="import.inner_class_name" v="false"/>
         <value n="import.narrow_threshold" v="-1"/>
         <value n="indent.block_children" v="true"/>
         <value n="indent.class_members" v="true"/>
         <value n="indent.control_blocks" v="false"/>
         <value n="indent.num_spaces" v="4"/>
         <value n="indent.replace_with_tabs" v="false"/>
         <value n="indent.switch_case" v="false"/>
         <value n="indent.tab_size" v="8"/>
         <value n="local.variable.prefix"/>
         <value n="local.variable.suffix"/>
         <value n="newline.after_switch_case" v="true"/>
         <value n="newline.array_braces" v="false"/>
         <value n="newline.block_braces" v="false"/>
         <value n="newline.catch" v="false"/>
         <value n="newline.class_braces" v="false"/>
         <value n="newline.else" v="false"/>
         <value n="newline.extends" v="false"/>
         <value n="newline.finally" v="false"/>
         <value n="newline.implements" v="false"/>
         <value n="newline.method_braces" v="false"/>
         <value n="newline.throws" v="false"/>
         <value n="newline.while" v="false"/>
         <value n="parameter.prefix"/>
         <value n="parameter.suffix"/>
         <value n="profile.name" v="Java Code Conventions"/>
         <value n="space.arguments_before" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.assign_around" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.binaryop_around" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.brace_before" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.brackets_within" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.colon_after" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.colon_before" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.comma_after" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.comma_before" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.keyword_after" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.parameters_before" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.parens_within" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.question_after" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.question_before" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.semicolon_after" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.semicolon_before" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.typecast_after" v="true"/>
         <value n="static.field.prefix"/>
         <value n="static.field.suffix"/>
         <value n="wrap.align" v="true"/>
         <value n="wrap.array_constant" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.binary_operator" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.dot_chain" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.extends" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.for_statement" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.invoke_arguments" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.line_width" v="120"/>
         <value n="wrap.modifiers" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.parameter_list" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.ques_operator" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.throws" v="1"/>
      </hash>
      <hash n="JDeveloper Classic">
         <value n="blanklines.after_last_member" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.before_field" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.before_first_class" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.before_first_member" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.before_member_class" v="1"/>
         <value n="blanklines.before_method" v="1"/>
         <value n="blanklines.empty_anonymous" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.empty_block" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.empty_class" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.empty_method" v="0"/>
         <value n="blanklines.imports_after" v="1"/>
         <value n="blanklines.package_after" v="1"/>
         <value n="blanklines.preserve_count" v="2"/>
         <value n="field.prefix"/>
         <value n="field.suffix"/>
         <value n="import.group_imports" v="true"/>
         <value n="import.group_package_depth" v="2"/>
         <value n="import.inner_class_name" v="false"/>
         <value n="import.narrow_threshold" v="-1"/>
         <value n="indent.block_children" v="true"/>
         <value n="indent.class_members" v="true"/>
         <value n="indent.control_blocks" v="false"/>
         <value n="indent.num_spaces" v="2"/>
         <value n="indent.replace_with_tabs" v="false"/>
         <value n="indent.switch_case" v="true"/>
         <value n="indent.tab_size" v="8"/>
         <value n="local.variable.prefix"/>
         <value n="local.variable.suffix"/>
         <value n="newline.after_switch_case" v="true"/>
         <value n="newline.array_braces" v="true"/>
         <value n="newline.block_braces" v="true"/>
         <value n="newline.catch" v="true"/>
         <value n="newline.class_braces" v="true"/>
         <value n="newline.else" v="true"/>
         <value n="newline.extends" v="true"/>
         <value n="newline.finally" v="true"/>
         <value n="newline.implements" v="true"/>
         <value n="newline.method_braces" v="true"/>
         <value n="newline.throws" v="true"/>
         <value n="newline.while" v="true"/>
         <value n="parameter.prefix"/>
         <value n="parameter.suffix"/>
         <value n="profile.name" v="JDeveloper Classic"/>
         <value n="space.arguments_before" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.assign_around" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.binaryop_around" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.brace_before" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.brackets_within" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.colon_after" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.colon_before" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.comma_after" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.comma_before" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.keyword_after" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.parameters_before" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.parens_within" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.question_after" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.question_before" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.semicolon_after" v="true"/>
         <value n="space.semicolon_before" v="false"/>
         <value n="space.typecast_after" v="true"/>
         <value n="static.field.prefix"/>
         <value n="static.field.suffix"/>
         <value n="wrap.align" v="true"/>
         <value n="wrap.array_constant" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.binary_operator" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.dot_chain" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.extends" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.for_statement" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.invoke_arguments" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.line_width" v="120"/>
         <value n="wrap.modifiers" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.parameter_list" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.ques_operator" v="1"/>
         <value n="wrap.throws" v="1"/>
      </hash>
   </hash>
   <value n="db.system.id" v="e1caeacf-6a86-4b8b-a503-e4d6b96030c9"/>
   <hash n="DBConfig">
      <hash n="EXTENSION"/>
      <value n="TNS_NAMES_DIR" v="O:\Dev6i\Sqlnet"/>
      <hash n="URLFileChooserPaths">
         <list n="ConfigClientPanel.Dialog.Home">
            <url path="../../../../../../../Oracl11GR2_64/product/11.2.0/client_1/"/>
                
                                 
                                         
                
                                   
                                         
         </list>
         <list n="TNS_NAMES_DIR">
            <url protocol="file" path="/O:/Dev6i/Sqlnet"/>
            <url protocol="file" path="/O:/Dev6i/Sqlnet/"/>
         </list>
      </hash>
      <value n="URLFileChooserPaths.persisted" v="true"/>
      <value n="USE_THICK_DRIVER" v="true"/>
   </hash>
   <hash n="DebugWindowOptions">
      <list n="UNINSTALLED_WINDOWS">
         <string v="Debugger.SmartWindow"/>
         <string v="Debugger.LocalsWindow"/>
         <string v="Debugger.WatchWindow"/>
         <string v="Debugger.StackWindow"/>
         <string v="Debugger.ThreadsWindow"/>
      </list>
   </hash>
      <value n="browserCmdLine" v="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe ${URL}"/>
      <list n="browserIconList">
         <string v="IE"/>
         <string v="CHROME"/>
      </list>
      <list n="browserIsDefaultList">
         <boolean v="true"/>
         <boolean v="false"/>
      </list>
      <list n="browserNameList">
         <string v="Internet Explorer"/>
         <string v="Chrome"/>
      </list>
      <list n="browserParamList">
         <string v="${URL}"/>
         <string v="${URL}"/>
      </list>
      <list n="browserPathList">
         <string v="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"/>
         <string v="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"/>
      </list>
      <value n="useEmbeddedBrowserForPreview" v="false"/>
   </hash>
</ide:preferences>
```

Comment: XSLT transformation would be the best way to handle the scenario

Comment: Please double-check the XML, it appears there's an opening `<hash>` node tag missing towards the end (immediatebly before `<value n="browserCmdLine" v="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe ${URL}"/>` perhaps?)

Comment: @ Yitzhak Khabinsky How are you handling XLST Transformation in that task?